# react script not working when sourced through external file

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code which works fine. When I comment out the react script at the bottom and add it to the clickme.js file I get unexpected token < on the first div in the return of the render function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/create-react-class@15.6.2/create-react-class.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.4.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='clickme.js'></script>

  <title>Click Me</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
     Count:<span id="cnt1">0</span>
     <button id='btn1' type='button' style="width:60px">JS only</button>
  </div>
    <br>
  <div>
     Count:<span id="cnt2">0</span>
     <button id='btn2' type='button' style="width:60px">Jquery</button>
  </div>
   <br>
  <div id='react-example'> </div>


 <script type='text/jsx'>
       var btnCSS = {
       width: '60px',
       textAlign:'center',
       padding:0,
       border:0
    };
    class Counter extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { count: 0};
       }

       incrementCount() {
          this.setState( {count: this.state.count + 1});
       }
       render() {
          return (
             <div> Count:{this.state.count}
                <button type="button" style={btnCSS}
                   onClick={ this.incrementCount.bind(this) }>React</button>
             </div>
          );
       }
    };

    ReactDOM.render(
                <Counter />,
                document.getElementById('react-example')
     ) 
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the clickme.js file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

var counter = Number(document.getElementById("cnt1").innerHTML);

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function(){
   counter = counter + 1;
   document.getElementById("cnt1").innerHTML=counter;
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){

var counter= Number($("#cnt2").html());

$("#btn2").click(function() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    $("#cnt2").html(counter);
 });
```

});

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var btnCSS = {
width: '60px',
textAlign:'center',
padding:0,
border:0
};
class Counter extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { count: 0};
}

incrementCount() {
  this.setState( {count: this.state.count + 1});
}
render() {
    return (
     <div> Count:{this.state.count}
        <button type="button" style={btnCSS}
           onClick={ this.incrementCount.bind(this) }>React</button>
     </div>
  );
```

}
   };

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Counter />,
document.getElementById('react-example')
)
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have to add the `type="text/jsx"` to the external script tag:

```
<script src="clickme.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
```

Comment: i added type='text/jsx' and get the following error message:  babel.min.js:24 Failed to load file:///C:/Users/Bob/Desktop/clickme.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: You need to run with a local server. If you don't have one, you could install and run http-server (`npm install http-server -g`)

Comment: so I tried that but it didn't work. I ran the index.html file and serving up static files like they were turtles strapped to rockets comes up just fine. Then I placed a copy of clickme.html and clickme.js in the index.html directory. When I add type='text/jsx' or type='text/babel'  in the clickme.html file to load clickme.js the file doesn't load. when it's not included I get the unexpected token error.

Comment: I'm sorry that it didn't work for you. Works for me in my testing. You need a web server because of browser sandbox security. Browsers won't load a file from the file system because, for example, a script could access a sensitive file and upload the contents without consent.